# How to get rid of histogram grids in Circos

Tags: visualization, circos

I am using Circos to plot some histograms. How can I get rid of the vertical grids in the example below?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the circos [grids lesson](http://circos.ca/tutorials/lessons/ticks_and_labels/grids/lesson).

Hope it useful and also here is the example circos out picture:  [image]